# Get the span of a list

Tags: python

I'm writing a function `def span(l)` where `l` is meant to be a list and it returns the range from smallest to largest.

The following is the code:

```
def span(l):
    l = l.sort()
    smallest = min(l)
    largest = max(l)
    return largest-smallest
```

My problem is that it doesn't recognize that `l` is a list. That is when I try to return `l` and I enter the following as input:

`>>>span([4,2,9,6,9])`

I keep getting an error.

Comment: Hey, my refrigerator isn't getting cold, can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: did you set the return keyword?

Comment: Please post how you have defined span()

Comment: In the future try `print`ing out some of your intermediate variables, your bug would have been immediately apparent.

Answer (score 5):

`list.sort` sorts a lists in place and returns `None`. When you reassigned `l = l.sort()`, `l` became None. It shocks me that this doesn't give you a `TypeError` when you do `min(l)`

More to the point you don't NEED to sort `l`. `max` and `min` work irrespective of sorting, so

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
unsorted_lst = [4,2,3,1,5]

max(lst), min(lst) == max(unsorted_lst), min(unsorted_lst)
```

Just do

```
def span(lst):
    return max(lst) - min(lst)
```

Comment: On a side note, avoid naming variables lowercase "el" `l`, uppercase "oh" `O`, or uppercase "eye" `I`. They're easy to mistake for ones and zeroes in code.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you mean, is this the error you got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-9b92b18b9c80> in <module>()
      7     return largest-smallest
      8 
----> 9 print span(l)

<ipython-input-133-9b92b18b9c80> in span(l)
      3 def span(l):
      4     l = l.sort()
----> 5     smallest = min(l)
      6     largest = max(l)
      7     return largest-smallest

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The problem is with this line
    l = l.sort()

If you read the [documentation of sort()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), you can see that :

> The sort() and reverse() methods modify the list in place for economy of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed list.

So l.sort() does not return anything. When you do l = l.sort(), you get nothing. To correct your code:

```
def span(l):
    l.sort()    # <- here is the fix
    smallest = min(l)
    largest = max(l)
    return largest-smallest
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the code for `span`, but if it was something like

```
def span(l):
    return max(l) - min(l)
```

if by `span` you mean "difference between largest and smallest item", or equivalently simple variations such as `return min(l), max(l)` if you mean "a two-items tuple with the smallest and largest item", &c, it's hard to guess how you could possibly go wrong.  So please **do** show code!-)